# adding a distance attr_accessor to a model only if location params are passed in

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, geolocation

I am currently working on a rails backend that is tied to both a web and iOS frontend.  On the iOS side we are currently passing in latitude and longitude then calculating distances to nearest objects on the server.

My problem is, in my controller before rendering the json for iOS, I have to loop through each object and add `object[:distance] = distance_calculation if params[:latitude] && params[:longitude]`.

I get depreciation warnings when adding arbitrary properties like that, and I would think there would be something better I could do.  I have thought about adding an `attr_accessor :distance` on the object but I am unable to set this based on parameters in the model since the model does not have access to parameters, I would still have to do the loop before json rendering.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: In the contoller#action I am rendering json in a respond_to block

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand why you're trying to set the distance on your models... The iOS client is sending a location, defined by lat and long, and you're trying to do what exactly?

Your objects are already geolocated, right? Otherwise how would you determine the nearest ones?

But anyways, to answer your question on setting the distance on your models, use an `attr_accessor`, like you said:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :distance
end
```

And in your controller

```
 object.distance = distance_calculation if params[:latitude] && params[:longitude]
```

If you have geolocated models and trying to compute distances etc, you might want to use a gem like [Geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder).

Comment: The objects are already geolocated, the iOS client needs the distance to these objects from its current location.  I already have the geolocation distance calculation taken care of, I was just curious if there was a way to return the distance without having to loop through each object in the controller.  The more I think about it now though, I dont see how there could be any other way.

Comment: Maybe that's what you're doing, but you should first find the nearest objects, and then only loop through them to the get the distances. Because let's say you have a million objects, there's no way you're going to load and iterate over this huge collection ;)

Comment: Robin, yeah our geolocation gem is only returning 30 at a time.  Thanks!